# Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

When I remove a page and add another page, it shows this error. Why does it do that? It says the error is located at the line "parent.removeChild(homePage);

```
    function onPlayButtonsClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //var level1Page = new Level1Page;
        parent.addChild(level1Page);
        parent.removeChild(homePage);
    }

private function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            vx = -5;
            side = true;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            vx = 5;
            side = true;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            vy = -5;
            up = true;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            vy = 5;
            up = true;
        }
    }

private function onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A || event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            vx = 0;
            side = false;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S || event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            vy = 0;
            up = false;
        }
    }
```

This is the code for my level1Page keyboard event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `#2025` error because your `homePage` object is not a child of the mentioned `parent`, to avoid such problem, try always to do like this :

```
yourObject.parent.removeChild(yourObject);
```

In your case it will be :

```
homePage.parent.removeChild(homePage);
```

You can take a look on my answer of this question :
[Remove Child and AS3 2025 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016001/remove-child-and-as3-2025-error/28016602#28016602).

Hope that can help.

Comment: That's odd. My game doesn't get the error if I do it that way, but instead my character doesn't move when level 1 is added. But if I do it my way, I still get the error but I can move my character that way... Do you know what's causing my character to freeze?

Comment: @Crook Did you have some code in your `homePage` ? If yes, could you show it, otherwise, could you show the code that you are using to move your character ?

Comment: public function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void
  {
   if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
   {
    _vx = -5;
   }
   else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
   {
    _vx = 5;
   }
   else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
   {
    _vy = -5;
   }
   else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
   {
    _vy = 5;
   }
  }

Comment: @Crook I meant, put the code in your question, but no problem. And this is the code of what (which object) or where you use it ?

Comment: It's for my player class.

Comment: @Crook Really it's not easy to know why your character doesn't move with the few details that you told me, but do you have some `KeyboardEvent` handlers in your `level1Page` ? Could you put more details (or code) about your project to understand the situation ?

Comment: Yes there is a keyboard event to control the background scrolling in my level1Page, I'll post it above.

Comment: @Crook In that case try to use one "global" handler for all your `KeyboardEvent`s, and it's better, with a main global loop. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862624/game-logic-and-game-loops-in-actionscript-3).

Comment: I don't really get it. Will it fix the problem?

Comment: @Crook Yes, because when you load your `level1Page` it intercepts all the keyboard actions so your player will not move!

Comment: I don't really get how to implement this. Am I supposed to put the keyboard event in my main class?