# Timer Efficiency

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, timer, actionscript

I'm working on an AS3 project and for one of the effects I use timers to switch the colors then stop. The function is below.

```
 //global variable
    private var valueAnimationTimer:Timer = new Timer(50);
    //constructor
    valueAnimationTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, scrollUp ); 
    //function
    private function scrollUp(e:TimerEvent):void
            {

                var i:int = e.currentTarget.currentCount as int;
                if (i < 10)
                {
                    if (colored){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            ChangeColor(ico, flickerColor);
                        }
                        else{
                            ico.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform();
                        }
                    }
                    tfValue.y -= 7.5;
                }
                else
                {
                    RemoveFilters(ico);
                    tfValue.y = ico.height / 2;
                    e.currentTarget.reset();
                    RemoveSprite(tfValue);
                    colored = false; 
                }
            }
```

Each character (object) has it's own version of this function and it happens at different times (like when it is injured or poisoned). The listener is added once in the constructor, it is only removed when the character dies and is removed from the stage. The issue here is after the timer is used on at least 3 characters, the frame rate begins to drop. Every time the function is called, the frame rate drops lower and lower.

What I don't understand is, if the timer is stopped, and the listeners are only added once so it doesn't overload the stack, then why does the frame rate begin to decline after the listener is actually used? It doesn't run forever only for a small amount of time, but it happens again and again. When the frame rate drops the entire program begins to lag badly and eventually freezes. I have no idea what is causing this

Comment: Timer listeners are a fairly inefficient way to handle timing in games. It's much better to have a single game loop that checks every cycle if something needs to be updated. With timers, you may have multiple listeners firing in a game cycle and if you have many characters set up like this, it puts strain on the player.

Comment: I see. I was looking through a different forum thread and someone said that AS3 can handle something like 50-100+ objects and their events easily so I thought everything would be dandy. Thanks :)

Comment: How efficient is the Event.ENTER_FRAME listener? Would AS3 be able to handle that one more efficiently?

Comment: Is more efficient to use a gameloop, one listener ENTER_FRAME on your game updating all objects. Check the answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862624/game-logic-and-game-loops-in-actionscript-3

Comment: wow, so separate the world and  first tier objects and so on and so on. I feel like I should have known this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware that inside of the Timer function, the first number is your count in MILLISECONDS and the second is repeat count

```
var fl_TimerInstance:Timer = new Timer(240000, 1);
```

So this example above is a 4 minute timer that repeats 1 time

I bring this up because yours is set for 50 milliseconds which is very quick lol